# Instantiate Show class for a new data type

Tags: haskell, show

I defined these datatype:

```
data Term = Symbol [Char] | Number [Int] 
data Exp = Fun (String, Term) | Exp (String, [Exp])
```

And then i wrote some Show rules:

```
instance Show Term where
  show (Symbol [x])     = [x]
  show (Symbol (x:xs))  = [x]++", "++(show (Symbol xs))

  show (Number [x])     = (show x)
  show (Number (x:xs))  = (show x)++", "++(show (Number xs))

instance Show Exp where
  show (Fun (name, args)) = name++"("++(show args)++")"
  show (Exp (name, args)) = name++"("++(show args)++")"
```

Now if i let:

```
bt = Exp("z", [Fun("f", Number [1,2,3]), Fun("g", Symbol ['a', 'b', 'c'])])
```

showing it i get:

```
z([f(1, 2, 3),g(a, b, c)])
```

I would prefer to have this representation:

```
z(f(1, 2, 3),g(a, b, c))
```

i.e. without square brackets inside.

Can someone help me?

I tried to add these statements:

```
instance Show [Exp] where
  show [x]    = show x
  show (x:xs) = (show x)++(show xs)
```

but `ghci` claims that it's note legal code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the `showList` function in your `Show` instance for `Exp`.

```
instance Show Exp where
  show (Fun (name, args)) = name++"("++(show args)++")"
  show (Exp (name, args)) = name++"("++(show args)++")"
  showList [] _ = ""
  showList [x] _ = show x
  showList (x:xs) _ = show x ++ "," ++ show xs
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply change this line:

```
  show (Exp (name, args)) = name++"("++(show args)++")"
```

... so that it says:

```
  show (Exp (name, args)) = name++"("++(intercalate ", " . map show $ args)++")"
```

The function [`intercalate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aintercalate) is from [`Data.List`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html).

Comment: The `Fun` case should be left unchanged, as its `args` is not a list.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that! Thanks.